# mysql not connecting to environment after ruby-2.2.2 upgade

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I have just upgrade our legacy ruby app from ruby-1.9.3 to ruby-2.2.2. The app runs fine locally, I have successfully deployed it to our staging environment but for some reason it is now having issues connecting to mysql.

```
May 19 16:09:43 io-sbx-app-01-a3 rails[30750]: Reconnected to ActiveRecord
May 19 16:09:38 io-sbx-app-01-a3 rails[30738]: Verified ActiveRecord connections
May 19 16:09:43 io-sbx-app-01-a3 rails[30750]: Disconnected from ActiveRecord
```

Is there anything I need to consider with regards to connecting to mysql ? We currently use the mysql2 adapter

Answer (score 0):

Here's what i can think of, with the information i have

1) see if the mysql service is up and running

2) see if the reconnect flag to true in database.yml.

3) in the staging environment, is the database service running in the same machine / on a different machine. If different machine, there might be some network related issues..

4) during your deployment process, do you re-start the mysql service. if not, it'd be good to try that..

5) you can check mysql.err and mysql.logs to see what happened from the database side of things..